# Firebase Auth + React - updateProfile throws error "cannot read properties of null (reading getIdToken)" after createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently trying to create an user authentication system with Firebase Authentication and React. I want my users to be able to supply their username (aka `displayName`) when signing up. Here's the current code for it:

The script with firebase initialization, `firebase.js`:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = { /* Config information goes here */ };

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
```

The script containing the authentication context and functions related to signing up and updating the profile, `AuthContext.jsx`:

```
import { auth } from "../firebase";
import { useState, useEffect, useContext, createContext } from "react";
import {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
    onAuthStateChanged,
    updateProfile
} from "firebase/auth";

const AuthContext = createContext();

export function useAuth() {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export function AuthProvider({children}) {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    function signup(email, password) {
        return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    }

    function updateInformation(name) {
        return updateProfile(currentUser, {displayName: name});
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscriber = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
            setIsLoading(true);
            setCurrentUser(user);
            setIsLoading(false);
        });
        return unsubscriber;
    }, []);

    const value = {
        currentUser,
        signup,
        updateInformation
    }

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
            {!isLoading && children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

The script containing the signing up page, `Signup.jsx`:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useAuth } from "../contexts/AuthContext";

function Signup() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const {signup, updateInformation} = useAuth();

    async function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            await signup(email, password);
            await updateInformation(username); // Error happens here
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Create an account</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" value={username} onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)} placeholder="Username"/>
                <input type="email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} placeholder="Email"/>
                <input type="password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} placeholder="Password"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Sign up"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Signup;
```

The idea behind this code is that first the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` function will be called, signing the user up and automatically signing them in. This will fire the callback function in `onAuthStateChanged`, which updates the `currentUser` state. Then the `updateProfile` function will be called, changing the `displayName` of the account held by `currentUser`. At least, this is what I thought would happen. However, when the code is run, an error is thrown by `updateProfile` saying that `currentUser` is null. Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you share the code where you are using `getIdToken()` ?

Comment: I didn't use `getIdToken()` anywhere in my code. I'm guessing it is called by `updateProfile`?

Comment: @Dharmaraj i just edited the question. Hopefully the problem is easier to understand now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  const createUser = (email, password, username) => {
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then(() => {
    // sendEmailVerification(auth.currentUser)
    updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
      displayName: "Jane Q. User",
    }).then(() => {
      console.log('Actualizado')
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    });
  })
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.

Answer (score 0):

I added auth.currentUser to the currentUser and got it to work.

From this:

```
    function updateInformation(name) {
    return updateProfile(currentUser, {displayName: name}); }
```

To this:

```
    function updateInformation(name) { // Update user info
    return updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {displayName: name}); }
```